# DDOS protection technique

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, ddos

I was going through `AWS` `CDN` and i saw it has `DDOS` protection. After searching on internet I understood `DDOS` attack. Wondering what are the techniques available which can prevent this.

one possible solution i can think of is whitelisting the user IP. but that may work only for very small user group.

Any links or information will be helpful

Comment: Rate limiting is one way. But it depends.

Comment: Thank you. But that may still allow unwanted request to reach the application.

Comment: You might want to look at https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS has build in protection from DDOS for every custom for free. It is called [AWS Shield Standard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-overview.html):

> All AWS customers benefit from the **automatic protections** of AWS Shield Standard, at **no additional charge**. [...] While AWS Shield Standard helps protect all AWS customers, you get particular benefit if you are using **Amazon CloudFront and Amazon Route 53**.

For more features (e.g. refund due to DDOS) can get [AWS Shield Advanced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/ddos-overview.html) which also protects:

- Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud
- Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)
- AWS Global Accelerator

However, if you are thinking about architecting your own **DDOS protection for your own applications**, AWS also provides a guide for that as well as best practices:

- [Tutorial: Implementing a DDoS-resistant website using AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-tutorials-ddos-cross-service.html)
- [Additional best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-tutorials-ddos-cross-service-best-practices.html)

There is also recent **AWS whitepaper** dedicated fully to protection against DDOS on AWS:

- [AWS Best Practices for DDoS Resiliency](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/DDoS_White_Paper.pdf)